# how can i break through self sign certification by using okhttpclient on Android

Tags: java, android

I using this code to obtain normal picture from normal url links. And its works!
But when I using this code to obtain picture from untrust url links it's not work!
My friend said "it's because of self sign certificate". Please show solution for me pls.

```
private Bitmap download_Image(String url) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException {
        Bitmap bmp = null;

        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        Certificate ca;

        try{

            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("10.34.250.12/api/config/v1/maps/imagesource/domain_0_1500368087062.jpg")
                    .build();


            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            String credential = Credentials.basic("dev", "dev12345");
            response.request().newBuilder().header("Authorization", credential).build();
            InputStream is = response.body().byteStream();
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            return bmp;
        }
        catch (Exception e){}
        return bmp;
    }
```

Comment: Error messages.  We like them.  Your question doesn't have one.  Please [edit].

Comment: [This technique](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/HTTPS#certificate-pinning) should cover self-signed certificates as well.